# Why in chrome button doesn't look good as in firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

I want to show button in chrome same as in mozilla firefox, here is the code:

```
.myButton {
     font-size: 14px;
     background:#e3e3e3;
     color:gray;
     padding:11px;
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 100%;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 4px;
     font: normal 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     text-align:center;
     display:inline-block;
     transition:all 0.3s;
     text-decoration:none;
     -webkit-appearance: button;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin:0;
     max-width:100%;
     vertical-align:baseline;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">Apply</a>
```

**Button in chrome:**

[image: Chrome Button]

**Button in Mozilla:**

[image: Mozilla Button]

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: button;` is only for Webkit browsers. Include `-moz-appearance: button;` along `-webkit-`.

Comment: to ensure both browsers look the same, use image.

Comment: What is the question? You want chrome to look like Firefox or Firefox to look like chrome

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Spot on with the problem area mate, but I think OP is looking for the reverse (that is removal of `-webkit-appearance`).

Comment: @Harry - I though OP wanted to make the button looks the "same" on Firefox as in Chrome. But anyway, here's a demo for the fixed button style: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/sb11h9ce/

Comment: The correct response is http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with the border and the background.

Both of wich are set by `-webkit-appearance: button;`
Because in CSS the last instruction you give is usually leading (e.a. if you set your background twice the last one will be used).

Remove `-webkit-appearance: button;` from your code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to be consistent on all browsers would be to use an APPLY image for your button, it would still be an anchor link but inside the link would be an . You could use photoshop to choose the button you like the best and use it as your link.